# how to get a field value in antd proform

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, ant-design-pro

I used the
`antd StepsForm`
to create a form in three steps, and I need to get the first card's field values in the first step separately and display them in a list by clicking the add button. how can I get these fields value separately?
I used `getFieldFormatValue` but it doesn't work and caused an error
here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { ProCard, ProForm, ProFormCheckbox, ProFormDatePicker, ProFormDateRangePicker, ProFormDigit, ProFormSelect, ProFormText, StepsForm } from "@ant-design/pro-components"
import { message, ConfigProvider, Button } from "antd"
import enUS from "antd/locale/en_US"

const waitTime = (time = 100) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true)
    }, time)
  })
}
const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    //const gageId = getFieldFormatValue("gageId")
    //console.log(gageId)
  }

  return (
    <ConfigProvider locale={enUS}>
      <StepsForm
        onFinish={async (values) => {
          console.log(values)
          await waitTime(1000)
          message.success("success")
        }}
        formProps={{
          validateMessages: {
            required: "please fill the input",
          },
        }}
      >
        <StepsForm.StepForm
          name="base"
          title="Gage Information"
          onFinish={async () => {
            await waitTime(2000)
            return true
          }}
          layout="horizontal"
        >
          <ProCard
            title="Basic Info"
            bordered
            headerBordered
            collapsible
            style={{
              marginBlockEnd: 16,
              minWidth: 800,
              maxWidth: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <ProFormText name="gageId" width="md" label="Gage Id" placeholder="Gage Id" rules={[{ required: true }]} />
            <ProFormText name="description" width="md" label="Description" placeholder="Gage Description" />
            <Button type="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
              Add
            </Button>
          </ProCard>
          <ProCard
            title="More Info"
            bordered
            headerBordered
            collapsible
            style={{
              marginBlockEnd: 16,
              minWidth: 800,
              maxWidth: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <ProFormText name="serialNumber" width="md" label="Serial Number" placeholder="Serial Number" />
            <ProFormText name="name" width="md" label="Name" placeholder="Name" />
          </ProCard>
        </StepsForm.StepForm>
        <StepsForm.StepForm title="Routines">
          <ProCard
            style={{
              minWidth: 800,
              marginBlockEnd: 16,
              maxWidth: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <ProFormText name="Address" width="md" label="Address" placeholder="Address" />
            <ProFormText name="email" width="md" label="Email" placeholder="email" />
          </ProCard>
        </StepsForm.StepForm>
        <StepsForm.StepForm name="time" title="Purchase Information">
          <ProCard
            style={{
              marginBlockEnd: 16,
              minWidth: 800,
              maxWidth: "100%",
            }}
          >
            <ProFormText name="Address" width="md" label="Address" placeholder="Address" />
            <ProFormText name="email" width="md" label="Email" placeholder="email" />
          </ProCard>
        </StepsForm.StepForm>
      </StepsForm>
    </ConfigProvider>
  )
}
export default App
```

Comment: i think you should use localstorage to save the datas that you filled before